# Como criar uma ALV com base em uma estrutura dinâmica?

Tags: erp, abap

Estou tentando agilizar processos já que por diversas vezes precisamos
gerar relatórios em ALVs.

A idéia é conseguir obter o metadados de uma estrutura ( Nome de Campo, Domínio, Descritivo )
e assim gerar o 'fieldcat' na função de criação da ALV e na sequência conseguir preenchê-la.

Ex.:

Percorrendo os campos da estrutura daria pra preencher a tabela de esqueleto.

```
CLEAR gs_s_fcat.
gs_s_fcat-fieldname = fieldname. " Nome do campo da Estrutura
gs_s_fcat-outputlen = size.      " O tamanho do conteúdo
gs_s_fcat-tabname   = table.     " Tabela
gs_s_fcat-coltext   = header.    " Texto do cabeçalho
gs_s_fcat-col_pos   = index.     " Índice da coluna
gs_s_fcat-emphasize = style.     " Estilo, cores e etc.
APPEND gs_s_fcat TO gt_t_fcat.
```

Chamar a criação da tabela genérica.

```abap
CALL METHOD cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
EXPORTING
  i_style_table             = 'X'
  it_fieldcatalog           = gt_t_fcat
IMPORTING
  ep_table                  = gt_generic_table
EXCEPTIONS
  generate_subpool_dir_full = 1
  OTHERS                    = 2.
```

{...} - Preencheria um field-symbol coom a mesma estrutura e usaria no display

```abap
CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
EXPORTING
  i_buffer_active          = 'X'
  i_callback_program       = sy-repid
  is_layout                = gs_layout
  it_fieldcat              = gt_t_fcat
TABLES
  t_outtab                 = <fs_table>
EXCEPTIONS
  program_error            = 1
  OTHERS                   = 2.
```

Idéias?

Comment: Não vai ser fácil achar quem possa responder, mas a questão é interessante. É provável que você precise trazer especialistas no assunto para o site :)

Comment: É verdade @bigown, precisamos de mais 'abapers' :)

Comment: Eu já fiz algo pareceido. Sei que tem uma tabela que armazena os campos das tabelas e estruturas mas não lembro qual era. Achei no google DD03L e DD03T, talvez sejam essas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei algumas formas diferentes de se obter o detalhamento de campos de estruturas.

Através do método da classe de assistência conforme abaixo:

```
tabela_de_detalhe ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'NOME_ESTRUTURA' ).
```

e a que eu achei melhor para os meus propósitos, a função a seguir.

```
CATSXT_GET_DDIC_FIELDINFO
```

O resultado final ficou assim:

Variáveis devidamente declaradas.

```
**---------------------------------------------------------------------*
**     Tabelas internas                                                *
**---------------------------------------------------------------------*
  DATA: lt_fields   TYPE ddfields,
        lt_fcat     TYPE lvc_t_fcat,
        lt_fcat_alv TYPE slis_t_fieldcat_alv.
**---------------------------------------------------------------------*
**     Estrutura                                                       *
**---------------------------------------------------------------------*
  DATA: ls_fcat     TYPE lvc_s_fcat,
        ls_fields   LIKE LINE OF lt_fields,
        ls_fcat_alv LIKE LINE OF lt_fcat_alv.
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*      Variaveis                                                       *
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
  DATA: lv_index  TYPE i.
```

A chamada da função que retorna o detalhe da estrutura submetida.

```
   CALL FUNCTION 'CATSXT_GET_DDIC_FIELDINFO'
    EXPORTING
      im_structure_name = structure_name
    IMPORTING
      ex_ddic_info      = lt_fields
    EXCEPTIONS
      failed            = 1
      OTHERS            = 2.

  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    RAISE structure_not_found.
  ENDIF.
```

Agora é preciso direcionar essa informação para a tabela que manterá o esqueleto da ALV.

```
LOOP AT lt_fields INTO ls_fields.

    CLEAR: ls_fcat.

    lv_index = lv_index + 1.

    MOVE-CORRESPONDING:  ls_fields to ls_fcat_alv,
                         ls_fields to ls_fcat.

    IF ls_fields-scrtext_m IS NOT INITIAL.
      ls_fcat-coltext   = ls_fields-scrtext_m.
    ELSEIF ls_fields-scrtext_l IS NOT INITIAL.
      ls_fcat-coltext   = ls_fields-scrtext_l.
    ELSEIF ls_fields-scrtext_s IS NOT INITIAL.
      ls_fcat-coltext   = ls_fields-scrtext_s.
    ELSEIF ls_fields-fieldtext IS NOT INITIAL.
      ls_fcat-coltext   = ls_fields-fieldtext.
    ENDIF.

    ls_fcat_alv-seltext_l = ls_fcat-coltext.

    ls_fcat-col_pos   = lv_index.
    ls_fcat-key       = ls_fields-keyflag.

    APPEND: ls_fcat to lt_fcat,
            ls_fcat_alv to lt_fcat_alv.
ENDLOOP.
```

> **Obs.:**
>
> - Optei pela função **CATSXT_GET_DDIC_FIELDINFO** por ela me retornar além do nome das colunas o descritivo, informações de domínio, tabela fonte e afins.
> - Eu mantive duas estruturas propositalmente a **lt_fcat** e a **lt_fcat_alv**, a primeira servirá para a construção da tabela dinâmica e outra para a exibição da ALV.

Espero ter auxiliado, abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Um ABAP aqui para tentar ajudar. Não sei se você ainda enfrenta este problema, mas uma possível solução seria usar as novas classes de ALV. A mais simples de todas já constrói o ALV sem te pedir o a especificação dos campos (FIELDCAT). Basta passar a tabela interna e o restante ela já faz, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
REPORT z_teste_brl.

DATA t_t000 TYPE TABLE OF t000 WITH DEFAULT KEY.

SELECT * FROM t000 INTO TABLE t_t000.

DATA o_alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
  IMPORTING
    r_salv_table = o_alv
  CHANGING
    t_table      = t_t000.

o_alv->display( ).
```

Pra tornar isso dinâmico, você pode mudar o programa acima para algo mais ou menos assim:

```
REPORT z_teste_brl.

PARAMETER tn TYPE dd02l-tabname OBLIGATORY.

DATA table_name TYPE string.
table_name = tn.

DATA line_type_native TYPE REF TO cl_abap_typedescr.
CALL METHOD cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name
  EXPORTING
    p_name         = table_name
  RECEIVING
    p_descr_ref    = line_type_native
  EXCEPTIONS
    type_not_found = 1
    OTHERS         = 2.

CHECK sy-subrc IS INITIAL.

DATA line_type TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr.
line_type ?= line_type_native.

DATA table_type TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr.
table_type = cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( p_line_type = line_type
                                         p_table_kind = cl_abap_tabledescr=>tablekind_std ).

DATA internal_table TYPE REF TO data.
CREATE DATA internal_table TYPE HANDLE table_type.

FIELD-SYMBOLS <internal_table> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
ASSIGN internal_table->* TO <internal_table>.

SELECT * FROM (tn) INTO TABLE <internal_table>.

DATA o_alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
  IMPORTING
    r_salv_table = o_alv
  CHANGING
    t_table      = <internal_table>.

o_alv->display( ).
```

Simples, né? Espero ter ajudado!